# Examples of groups

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

If B is a groups and b is in B, what are some examples where |b| is greater than or equal to |b^2| and |b|=|b^2|? And also how did you figure this out?

Comment: How do you define $|b|$ for an arbitrary group?

Comment: I'm not sure, there's nothing stating that.

Comment: I'm not sure if that was @Mindlack's question, but it isn't obvious what you mean by $|b|$. is that the order of b in the group? an arbitrary group doesn't have an "absolute value". you should elaborate more in your question

Comment: There's no other information in the question I'm trying to tackle, so I'm unable to elaborate more

Comment: So are you asking a question here that you don't understand the notation in it? where is the question from? what have you learned about group theory already?

Comment: @GuySa The notation $|b|$ for the order of an element is not uncommon. I was taught it as an undergrad, and I am sure it appears in many books. My reading of the above exchange is simply that the OP has no idea that other people have not come across this notation before, because (list most people in their situation!) they know of no other notation.

Answer (score 1):

In $(\mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z, +)$ the order of $2$ is equal to the order of $4$, i.e. $5$. That is a general fact that in a group whose order is equal to a prime number $p$, the order of all elements is equal to $p$ except for the identity element.

But in $(\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z, +)$, the order of $2$ is $6$ while the order of $4$ is $3$.